Do you say "I will look/watch out for my friend that needs to be protected" or "I will look/watch out for the one that might hurt my friend"?
What is the meaning of the preposition "for" in "watch out for" and "watch out for"?
This are examples from dictionaries
You should look out for pickpockets. (in this case, pickpockets are the bad one who will do bad things to you)
You need to look out for your little sister on this trip, OK? (in this case, your little sister is the one that you need to protect)
And It seems "look out for" and "watch out for" are the same.
A is the person needing to be protected and B is the bad person that wants to harm A.
C is A's friend.
So, is it correct for C to say "I will look out for A"/"I will watch out for A" or "I will look out for B"/"I will watch out for B"?

Preposition for has the same meaning in both senses (it denotes purpose). The difference lies in the non-explicit (but usually, contextually obvious) specific purpose as it relates to the explicitly-specified subject - looking / watching out for the benefit / protection of the sister, or for [the avoidance of] bad things [from the bad person].

The phrasal verb look out for has both meanings, as explained in OLD and shown in its two examples in sense B1:

look out for somebody


​to take care of somebody and make sure nothing bad happens to them


You should look out for yourself from now on.


You should look out for pickpockets.

look out for
Watch out with for also has both meanings, as shown in these examples in M+W:

Manage water, watch out for rattlesnakes and bears, try not to fall off your bike.


Please watch out for one another and keep our communities strong!

watch out
Hence the OP’s suggestions are fine:
I will look (or 'watch') out for A (or 'B').
